# Why does Gulp finish without transpiling my my ES6 code?

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I have a folder containing some `.js` files, written in pre-ES2015 JavaScript, along with a corresponding `gulpfile.js`, to compile my code. Now, I'm trying to add babel so that I can start writing code in in ES6.

After installing the npm packages I thought I would need and then running gulp, it finishing compiling without any issues, but my ES6 code isn't transpiled (i.e., `const` doesn't become `var`, arrow functions still present in the compiled code).

**What I've tried**:

In gulpfile.js, I've tried a few different values for the presets option -- `['es2015']`, `['babel-preset-es2015']`, and `['babel-preset-env']`.

But one of 2 things happens: 1. gulp finishes without errors, 2. the message `Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory...` is returned.

Could this be a versioning issue? Or perhaps I haven't configured my babel-preset correctly?

(I've included below my `package.json`, as well as the relevant part of my `gulpfile.js`)

**package.json**:

```
    {
        "name": "SA",
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "description": "my SA code",
        "devDependencies": {
            "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
            "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
            "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
            "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
            "del": "^2.2.2",
            "eslint": "^3.19.0",
            "gulp": "^4.0.2",
            "gulp-babel": "^7.0.1",
            "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
            "gulp-jscs": "^4.1.0",
            "gulp-jscs-stylish": "^1.4.0",
            "gulp-jshint": "^2.1.0",
            "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
            "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
            "jshint": "^2.9.5",
            "jshint-stylish": "^2.2.1"
        },
        "main": "SA",
        "dependencies": {
            "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
            "lodash": "^4.17.15"
        },
        "scripts": {
            "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
        },
        "author": "",
        "license": "ISC",
        "repository": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "[github URL]"
        },
        "keywords": []
    }
```

**gulpfile.js** (including relevant parts):

```
    var babel = require('gulp-babel'),
        concat = require('gulp-concat'),
        del = require('del'),
        gulp = require('gulp'),
        jscs = require('gulp-jscs'),
        jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
        rename = require('gulp-rename'),
        uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

    function createBuildTask(destination) {
        var sourceArray = [
            destination + '/config/mobileCheck.js',
            destination + '/config/account.js',
            'common/api.js',
            destination + '/config/utilityFunctions.js',
            destination + '/config/runFirst.js',
            destination + '/' + destination + '-main.js'
        ];

        return function () {
            return gulp.src(sourceArray, {'allowEmpty': true})
                .pipe(concat(destination + '-built-main.js'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(destination + '/dist'))
                .pipe(babel({
                    'presets': ['babel-preset-env']
                }))
                .pipe(uglify())
                .pipe(rename({
                    'extname': '.min.js'
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(destination + '/dist'));
        };
    }
```

Comment: You've installed `@babel/preset-env` but you said you tried referencing `babel-preset-env`. You seem to be using a mix of Babel 7 and Babel 8. You should make sure you're using one or the other and not both.